# How can I add this ticks color in Y axis in chart js?

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, jscharts

How can I add this tick color in chart js y axis. I am using **version 2.9.4**

[image]

I have tried like below way but no any impact.

```
xAxes: [{
            barThickness: 65,  // number (pixels) or 'flex'
            gridLines: {
                zeroLineColor: '#000',
                borderDash: [8, 4],
            },
            ticks: {
                fontColor: "black",
                fontSize: 14,
                fontStyle: "bold",
                tickColor: 'red'
            },
            grid: {
                tickColor: '#000'
            },
      }],
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that is impossible to do what you want to achieve. According to [docs](https://monstasat.github.io/chartjs-ocaml/chartjs/Chartjs/class-type-ticks/index.html) the methods allowed for `ticks` are:

- `callback`: Returns the string representation of the tick value as it should be displayed on the chart;
- `display`: If true, show tick marks;
- `fontColor`: Font color for tick labels;
- `fontFamily`: Font family for the tick labels, follows CSS font-family options;
- `fontSize`: Font size for the tick labels;
- `fontStyle`: Font style for the tick labels, follows CSS font-style options (i.e. normal, italic, oblique, initial, inherit);
- `reverse`: Reverses order of tick labels;
- `minor`: Minor ticks configuration. Omitted options are inherited from options above;
- `major`: Major ticks configuration. Omitted options are inherited from options above.

Comment: In version 3 they have used in there example 
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#ticks-and-tick-marks

Comment: Yes but you said that you are using version 2.9.4

Comment: Yes my version is 2.9.4

Comment: This `tickColor` could be a new feaure introduced in version 3. I think...